# load: class com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld.class not found

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I am learning Applet which is inside the Java tutorial on Youtube. When I complied the code using IntelliJ, everything was going well. The Applet Viewer worked fine too.

But when I inserted the applet code inside the html file( which I named it `index.html`), and also i copied the `HelloWorld.class` to the desktop (which has the main content) then I opened the index.html then found just blank in the browser.

Here's my `HelloWorld.java` & `index.html`

### HelloWorld.java

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet{

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("wow ",25, 25);
    }
}
```

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <applet code="/Users/Peterhon/Desktop/HelloWorld.class" width="400" height="100"></applet>

</body>
</html>
```

When I ran applet viewer index.html, I got the errors shown below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/Peterhon/Desktop/HelloWorld (wrong name: com/example/helloworld/HelloWorld)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:217)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:152)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:626)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:804)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:733)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: give the applet class Actual path in ur computer
e.g.
`<applet code="c:/HelloWorld.class" width="400" height="100"></applet>`

Comment: @JBALI i have tried to do this but still got the similar errors which have been updated above. I hope you will see that :-)

Comment: The code attribute here `<applet code="/Users/Peterhon/Desktop/HelloWorld.class" width="400" height="100"></applet>` should be the fully qualified name of the class, so `<applet code="com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld" width="400" height="100"></applet>` ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson What do you mean????

Comment: What don't you understand?  (And note that adding four '?' does not help clarity **at all.**)

Comment: @AndrewThompson what's the meaning of `qualified name of the class`?

Comment: *"what's the meaning of qualified name of the class?"*  The **fully** qualified name of the class is the packages of the class, in order, each separated by a dot (`.`) followed by the class name.  Something like `/Users/Peterhon/Desktop/HelloWorld.class` is the name and path of a class file on the local file system, whereas `com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld` might be the ***fully qualified name*** of that same class.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you Thompson. Really appreciate your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the `HelloWorld.class` by compiling the class in DOS "assuming you use windows" i.e.: `javac HelloWorld.java`, this will generate `HelloWorld.class` - Make sure the `HelloWorld.class` and the .html file are in the same place, let's say in `C:` drive.
2. Change the line in the html page

   ```
   <applet code="/Users/Peterhon/Desktop/HelloWorld.class" width="400" height="100"></applet>
   ```

   to this line:

   ```
   <applet code="HelloWorld.class" width="400" height="100"></applet>
   ```
3. If Java security settings not allowing you to show the applet, add the html file path in the trusted site in Java control in Windows Control Panel e.g. `localhost//test.html`

Comment: I used mac but i have done the first and second step just like you wrote here. But I didn't know how to do the third step on mac

Comment: @PeterTsung *"But I didn't know how to do the third step on mac"*  The applet will need to be digitally signed before the public can see it.  Once an applet is digitally signed, part 3 of the advice above becomes completely irrelevant.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you Thompson. : -)